# Installing Python modules without shell access

Tags: python, shell, module, nltk

I am trying to install [NLTK](http://nltk.org) to a server on which I don't have shell access. I can run Python code perfectly fine, though. NLTK's installation [instructions](http://nltk.org/install.html) don't detail how I should go about doing this. If possible, I would like to install NLTK in a /modules folder, and keep future modules in the same folder. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea; highly tacky, but it should work:

Use python's `os.system` to execute commands through python, on the shell.

Where the instructions say `sudo easy_install pip`, do this in python instead:

```
os.system("sudo easy_install pip")
```

The issue with doing this though, is that it becomes difficult to supply the sudo password. This can be fixed by running python as a sudo user (assuming you are able to do so) and them doing `os.system("easy_install pip")`.

Also, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112737/how-to-gain-root-privileges-in-python-via-a-graphical-sudo) might help with `sudo` difficulties

Hope this helps

Comment: He's running it on a server. By that, I presume he means something like a shared host. Thus `easy_install` isn't how he'll need to install it, and `sudo` won't be feasible at all.

Comment: I tried, but I think Chris is right. When I run the commands, Python just stops executing code and no new folders appear in any of my directories. I might be able to get past the sudo password issue by temporarily adjusting permissions, but after that I don't know where to go.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need sudo access to get the NLTK running on a server, just install the packages in your own space. First I'd just try `easy_install` without `sudo`. But maybe there's no `easy_install`, or maybe the server blocks you from launching arbitrary processes-- I would.

In that case, collect the required modules in a `site-packages` folder on your home box. Once you get it working there, you can drop it to the server and adjust PYTHONPATH (or `sys.path` from inside python) to find it. I've done this and it was pretty straightforward. If you can see the errors python throws when it fails to find something on the server, you can easily add any packages you forgot the first time around.